# Use of '%06.3f' in a C program

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int Fahrenheit;

    for (Fahrenheit = 0; Fahrenheit <= 300; Fahrenheit = Fahrenheit + 20)
        printf("%3d %06.3f\n", Fahrenheit, (5.0/9.0)*(Fahrenheit-32));
}
```

Output of the source above:

```
  0 -17.778
 20 -6.667
 40 04.444
 60 15.556
 80 26.667
100 37.778
120 48.889
140 60.000
160 71.111
180 82.222
200 93.333
220 104.444
240 115.556
260 126.667
280 137.778
300 148.889
```

Please explain to me the function of '06.3f' in the 'printf' function in the program above.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 3):

`0` fill with 0 on the left
`6` the string should be at least 6 characters long
`.3` precision is 3 digits after the decimal point
`f` it accepts a `float` (or `double`) variable

Comment: `f` is for `float` or `double` (in this case `double` is being passed). And the 6 includes the decimal point.

Comment: Technically, `%f` accepts only `double`, but when `float` is passed through variadic arguments, it is automatically converted to `double`.

Comment: But -6.667 (second line of output) isn't 6 characters long, and hasn't been filled with zeros. Likewise in other cases.

Comment: `-6.667` **is** 6 characters long. The count includes everything, the `-`, the `.`,...